# Highlight panel is not refreshing

Tags: page-layout

I am updating the case status through vf page,its updating in the record but status is not updating in highlight panel in service cloud console unless we refresh the page.

I there any possibility to refresh highlight panel after updating the record.

Thanks,
Suresh.

Comment: Where is the VF Page embedded? Is it a Custom Console Component

Answer (score 0):

Please refer Salesforce Console Integration Toolkit.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_refreshprimarytabbyid.htm

refreshPrimaryTabById()
Refreshes a primary tab specified by ID, including its subtabs. This method can't refresh subtabs with URLs to external pages or Visualforce pages. This method is only available in API version 22.0 or later.

Syntax

sforce.console.refreshPrimaryTabById(id:String, active:Boolean, (optional)callback:Function, (optional)fullRefresh:Boolean)

this will give you idea about how to refresh primary-tab.

Hope this is what you needed otherwise please provide more details so that I can help you better.

Thanks,
Nachiket